# How to extract string value in html with parsing in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the string value for each link. (For example, like Pennsylvania)

```
 <li class="facetbox-shownrow ">
    <a href="/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/9043/cosponsors?r=1&amp;s=1&amp;q=%7B%22search%22%3A%5B%22H.R.9043%22%2C%22H.R.9043%22%5D%2C%22cosponsor-state%22%3A%22Pennsylvania%22%7D" title="include this search constraint" id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvania">
        Pennsylvania        <span id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvaniacount" class="count">[1]</span>    </a>
</li>
   </a>
```

But since there are title and id attributes, I am a bit confused about how to do it. I get a null result when I display my array. Here is my code :

```
  for link in links_array:

    main_url_link = base_url_link + link
    html_page_link = requests.get(main_url_link)
    soup_link = BeautifulSoup(html_page_link.text, 'html.parser')
    allData_link = soup_link.findAll('li',{'class':'facetbox-shownrow'})
  
    distric = [y.text_content() for y in allData_link]
    district_array.append(distric)


district_array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.stripped_strings` to generate a list of strings of elements in your selection and pick / slice the result - In this case pick first element to get *Pennsylvania*:

```
[list(x.stripped_strings)[0] for x in soup.find_all('li',{'class':'facetbox-shownrow'})]
```

**Note** *In new code `find_all()` should be used, `findAll()` actually still works but is very old syntax*

To get the `href`:

```
[x.a['href'] for x in soup.find_all('li',{'class':'facetbox-shownrow'})]
```

#### Example

With multiple `li` tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<li class="facetbox-shownrow ">
    <a href="/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/9043/cosponsors?r=1&amp;s=1&amp;q=%7B%22search%22%3A%5B%22H.R.9043%22%2C%22H.R.9043%22%5D%2C%22cosponsor-state%22%3A%22Pennsylvania%22%7D" title="include this search constraint" id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvania">
        Pennsylvania        <span id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvaniacount" class="count">[1]</span>    </a>
</li>
<li class="facetbox-shownrow ">
    <a href="/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/9043/cosponsors?r=1&amp;s=1&amp;q=%7B%22search%22%3A%5B%22H.R.9043%22%2C%22H.R.9043%22%5D%2C%22cosponsor-state%22%3A%22Pennsylvania%22%7D" title="include this search constraint" id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvania">
        Main        <span id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvaniacount" class="count">[1]</span>    </a>
</li>
<li class="facetbox-shownrow ">
    <a href="/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/9043/cosponsors?r=1&amp;s=1&amp;q=%7B%22search%22%3A%5B%22H.R.9043%22%2C%22H.R.9043%22%5D%2C%22cosponsor-state%22%3A%22Pennsylvania%22%7D" title="include this search constraint" id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvania">
        California        <span id="facetItemcosponsor-statePennsylvaniacount" class="count">[1]</span>    </a>
</li>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

[list(x.stripped_strings)[0] for x in soup.find_all('li',{'class':'facetbox-shownrow'})]
```

#### Output

```
['Pennsylvania', 'Main', 'California']
```

Comment: I just realized that after I tried what you said. I cannot get the link in links_array. But when I display just links_array, I can get the output. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: If you mean the href with link, then take a look in my answer I updated it, else give some more context please. thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I posted another question about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575359/extracting-text-from-parsed-html-with-python